# Problem_ with connecting to a OpenVPN Server

Tags: linux, openvpn

My client has given me a OpenVPN client file (`.ovpn`) and I have to connect to his server. I have no experience with OpenVPN.

I installed it and tried this command:

```
openvpn --config ./client_file.ovpn --remote <address>
```

But it freezes at "Initialization sequence started".

What appears on screen is :

```
Wed Jul 13 17:26:08 2011 OpenVPN 2.1.0 i486-pc-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [PF_INET6] [eurephia] built on Jul 20 2010
Wed Jul 13 17:26:08 2011 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Wed Jul 13 17:26:08 2011 /usr/bin/openssl-vulnkey -q -b 1024 -m <modulus omitted>
Wed Jul 13 17:26:09 2011 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Wed Jul 13 17:26:09 2011 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jul 13 17:26:09 2011 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jul 13 17:26:09 2011 LZO compression initialized
Wed Jul 13 17:26:09 2011 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:168 EF:68 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Wed Jul 13 17:26:10 2011 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Wed Jul 13 17:26:10 2011 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'ee93268d'
Wed Jul 13 17:26:10 2011 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'bd577cd1'
Wed Jul 13 17:26:10 2011 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]200.52.42.236:444 [nonblock]
Wed Jul 13 17:26:11 2011 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]200.52.42.236:444
Wed Jul 13 17:26:11 2011 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->200000] S=[16384->200000]
Wed Jul 13 17:26:11 2011 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Wed Jul 13 17:26:11 2011 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]200.52.42.236:444
Wed Jul 13 17:26:11 2011 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]200.52.42.236:444, sid=df9a1fe0 57e10cfd
Wed Jul 13 17:26:13 2011 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /CN=OpenVPN_CA
Wed Jul 13 17:26:13 2011 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Wed Jul 13 17:26:13 2011 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /CN=OpenVPN_Server
Wed Jul 13 17:26:17 2011 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128   bit key
Wed Jul 13 17:26:17 2011 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication                                                                            
Wed Jul 13 17:26:17 2011 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key                                                                                         
Wed Jul 13 17:26:17 2011 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication                                                                            
Wed Jul 13 17:26:17 2011 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA                                                                                
Wed Jul 13 17:26:17 2011 [OpenVPN_Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]200.52.42.236:444                                                                                 
Wed Jul 13 17:26:19 2011 SENT CONTROL [OpenVPN_Server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)                                                                                                   
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,explicit-exit-notify,topology subnet,route-delay 5 30,dhcp-pre-release,dhcp-renew,dhcp-release,route-metric 101,ping 5,ping-restart 40,socket-flags TCP_NODELAY,redirect-private local,redirect-private bypass-dhcp,redirect-private bypass-dns,route-gateway 10.10.0.1,route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0,route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0,comp-lzo yes,ifconfig 10.10.0.103 255.255.255.0'                                                                                                     
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: dhcp-pre-release (2.1.0)                                                   
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: dhcp-renew (2.1.0)                                                         
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: dhcp-release (2.1.0)                                                       
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified           
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 OPTIONS IMPORT: --explicit-exit-notify can only be used with --proto udp                                                                                   
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 OPTIONS IMPORT: LZO parms modified
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 OPTIONS IMPORT: --socket-flags option modified
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 Socket flags: TCP_NODELAY=1 succeeded
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 ROUTE default_gateway=192.168.1.1
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Jul 13 17:26:20 2011 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.10.0.103 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 broadcast 10.10.0.255
Wed Jul 13 17:26:25 2011 /sbin/route add -net 10.8.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.10.0.1 metric 101
Wed Jul 13 17:26:25 2011 /sbin/route add -net 10.9.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.10.0.1 metric 101
Wed Jul 13 17:26:25 2011 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Comment: Can you do a pastebin of the output? (Or what gets logged to syslog). There isn't just one standard config for openvpn, it supports many options and connection methods. The output would be helpful in diagnosing it.

Comment: Does `openvpn` have a verbose mode? It should show all the details of what's going on here. See if it has a `-v` option or similar.